# jQuery Remote Validation Forces Double-Click to Submit Form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am attempting to validate a form field remotely. If the field receives focus while I'm on the page, everything works great. However, if the field *never* receives focus, the form requires I click the "Submit" button twice in order to successfully submit.

I'd like it to either only validate if the field receives focus or somehow stop the form from requiring two clicks to submit. Anyone have any ideas?

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        project: {
            required: true,
            remote: "check.php"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        project: {
            required: "Required.",
            remote: "Check Failed."
        }
    },
});

<input type="text" name="project" id="project" value="X"/>
```

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: It should work.  Have you tried using just one input field as in your sample?

Comment: I had this same issue, click 1 hits the remote validation for a field. Click 2 submits the form. To resolve I just changed the SUBMIT from an <Input> tag to a <Button> tag. Now on click it does remote validation and on success posts the form.

Answer (score 10):

```
Instead of making ajax setup to false you can just set "project" "remote" async to false like this

$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        project: {
            required: true,
            remote: {url:"check.php", async:false}
        }
    },
    messages: {
        project: {
            required: "Required.",
            remote: "Check Failed."
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Making request not async may freeze whole UI. Be careful. Definitely answer from @Pé de Leão is better

Answer (score 5):

What is the name of your submit button? jQuery Validate doesn't like the name "submit." I changed the name of my submit button to "submitter," and the problem went away. Check out this link: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/58

Comment: I confirm this works. The other solutions (where suggesting adding "async:false") would actually cause a problem when the form contains other mandatory (required) fields. When "async:false", the "required" fields would be ignored and users can bypass it and leave the fields empty. Replacing the submit button name to "submitter" fixes this.

Answer (score 4):

You can resolve the problem by adding:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: false
});
```

Before you call the validation plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and 
remote: {url:"check.php", async:false}
worked for me.